# OnsenUI上のHTML下のセグメントで別のHTMLを表示させる領域を確保するには

Tags: monaca, onsen-ui

OnsenUIのCSSドキュメントにセグメントの項目がありますがセグメントの項目をタップすることでセグメントより下部分に対応したページを表示させたいと思っています。わからないことはセグメントによるページ遷移とセグメントを配置しているページ領域に別のhtmlを読み込ませる方法です。わからないのでどなたかご教授をお願いします。

Comment: ありがとうございます。ons-sliding-menuでこんな使い方があるとは思わなかったです。ぜひ参考にさせていただきます。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

本来こういうやり方が正しいかどうなのかわかりませんが、工夫すればそれらしいことはできます。
ページの切り替えに`ons-sliding-menu`を使用します。
`ons-toolbar`にセグメントを配置し、タップ時に`ons-sliding-menu`の`setMainPage`メソッドを呼び出します。
各ページは`ons-toolbar`の下に隠れるので、上から45pxずらして表示させます。

あとは試行錯誤しながら実現してみてください。

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src *; style-src * 'unsafe-inline'; script-src * 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'">
    <script src="components/loader.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="components/loader.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
    <script>
        ons.bootstrap();
    </script>
    <style>
        #headerSegment {
            width:280px;
            margin: auto;
        }
        #page1Div {
            margin-top: 45px;
            height: 100%;
            background-color: #fbb;
        }
        #page2Div {
            margin-top: 45px;
            height: 100%;
            background-color: #bfb;
        }
        #page3Div {
            margin-top: 45px;
            height: 100%;
            background-color: #bbf;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <ons-sliding-menu var="app.menu" main-page="one.html" swipeable="false"></ons-sliding-menu>
    <ons-toolbar fixed-style>
        <div class="center">
            <div id="headerSegment" class="button-bar">
              <div class="button-bar__item" onclick="app.menu.setMainPage('one.html')">
                <input type="radio" name="segment-a" checked>
                <button class="button-bar__button">One</button>
              </div>

              <div class="button-bar__item" onclick="app.menu.setMainPage('two.html')">
                <input type="radio" name="segment-a">
                <button class="button-bar__button">Two</button>
              </div>

              <div class="button-bar__item" onclick="app.menu.setMainPage('three.html')">
                <input type="radio" name="segment-a">
                <button class="button-bar__button">Three</button>
              </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </ons-toolbar>    
    <ons-template id="one.html">
        <ons-page>
            <div id="page1Div">
                one.html
            </div>
        </ons-page>
    </ons-template>
    <ons-template id="two.html">
        <ons-page>
            <div id="page2Div">
                two.html
            </div>
        </ons-page>
    </ons-template>
    <ons-template id="three.html">
        <ons-page>
            <div id="page3Div">
                three.html
            </div>
        </ons-page>
    </ons-template>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。
申し訳ないですが説明不足で言い方が悪かったです。セグメントの下にページが表示された状態で切り替えるということをしたかったですが可能でしょうか？

Comment: @NaoTera であれば、具体的にどのような状態からどのような状態にしたいか質問内容を編集してください。この回答は削除します。

Comment: @NaoTera 回答を書き直しました。